# MKMapView Object is unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, overlays

I've written these two functions to draw overlay and working fine at `viewDidLoad()`.

However, I have to display updated overlay by passing new coordinates on a click event.

First function is to get Latitudes and Longitudes of locations in `CLLocationCoordinate2D` type `Array`. Second function is to draw an overlay with those coordinates.

Problem I'm facing is `MKMapView` object in function `drawpolyline(loclist: Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D>)`  nil every time I call this function on a click.

Here is the function:

```
func drawline(locs: Array<Location>){
    var loclist: Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D> = []

    if (locs.count > 3){

        for loc in locs{
            if (loc.gps == 1){
                let cord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: loc.lat!, longitude: loc.lon!)
                loclist.append(cord)
                }
            }
        }

   drawpolyline(loclist: loclist)

}
```

Function to draw overlay is:

```
func drawpolyline(loclist: Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D>){
    if(loclist != nil && loclist.count > 1){

         if let overlays = self.mainMapView?.overlays {
            self.mainMapView.removeOverlays(overlays)
            }
        if let annotations = self.mainMapView?.annotations {
            self.mainMapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
            }

        let startmark = loclist.first
        let endmark = loclist.last
        let cord1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (startmark?.latitude)!, longitude: (startmark?.longitude)!)

        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: loclist, count: loclist.count)
        print(polyline.pointCount)

        let mapAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation();
        mapAnnotation.title = Common.SelectedDevice?.dn;
        mapAnnotation.subtitle = Common.SelectedDevice?.dn;
        mapAnnotation.coordinate = cord1
        self.iconImage = Common.getIcon((Common.SelectedDevice?.icon)!, ign:(Common.SelectedDevice?.ign!)!)
        self.addDefaultMapPin("Start" , coordinates: startmark!)
        self.addDefaultMapPin("end" , coordinates: endmark!)

            self.mainMapView.add(polyline)
            self.mainMapView.addAnnotation(mapAnnotation);
            self.zoomPolyline(polyline)


    }
    else{
        configureMap()
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the crash?

Comment: `self.mainMapView.add(polyline) ` crashes everytime

Comment: Is `self.mainMapView` nil or `polyline` nil?

Comment: its `self.mainMapView` is nil every time i used it in this function or in any other. it works fine when i call it at launch time in `viewDidLoad()` but after that it shows nill error and crashes the app

Comment: When is `drawline()` called exactly? What triggers it? " I have to display updated overlay by passing new coordinates on a click event."

Comment: actually I'm calling this `drawline()` from another controller, the function `drawpolyline()` is called inside first function. first function works fine. the problem is in `drawpolyline() `

Comment: From another viewController? Explains the logic linking these two then.

Comment: the first function is to get an array of locations coming from another controller. this function get the latitude and longitude from locations and append those into array of CLLocationCoordinate2D. second function is to draw polyline with those coordinates.

Comment: *actually I'm calling this drawline() from another controller*--Then `self` inside `drawpolyline()` is the other controller, and `the_other_controller.mainMapView` doesn't exist.

Comment: The how can I access this `mainMapView` in this function?